# Why can't simple web pages be displayed when used Django2.2?

Tags: python, django

## This is the error it reported：

1:

```
t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 9737: illegal multibyte sequence
```

2：

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

## my solution

And i had add `(# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-)` in view.py and urls.py, but it still not worked.

### url.py(part)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', GeneView.as_view(), name='gene')
]
```

### view.py

```
class GeneView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        render(request, "index.html")
```

### setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.gene_ex',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

## result

only the error of "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator." on my curent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `View` should return the result of `render`:

```
class GeneView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using class based view you just have to right template_name = 'index.html' to render a template